# Как получить фокус для JavaFX приложения из другого окна?

Tags: java, javafx, focus

Когда вызываю приложение по горячим клавишам (alt+shift+v) делаю `stage.show()` и фокус не возвращается назад, а остается на предыдущем окне. В качестве глобального слушателя использую [JnativeHook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook). Пробовал вызывать `requestFocus()` и `toFront()` для `stage` и `node` - не помогает. Такая же ситуация и со `swing` приложением. Видел решение использовать `java.awt.Robot` - как только появляется окно, то жать мышкой по нему при помощи `Robot`, но мне этот вариант не подходит. Как можно вернуть фокус?
Вот пример кода:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ShowStageTest extends Application{

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());

    private static final int WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 400;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.setLevel(Level.WARNING);

        Application.launch(ShowStageTest.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

        primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        primaryStage.focusedProperty().addListener((ov, t, t1) -> {
            if (t) {
                primaryStage.hide();
            }
        });

        ListView<String> itemList = new ListView<>();
        itemList.setPrefSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT - HEIGHT / 10);
        itemList.setFixedCellSize(HEIGHT / 10);

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setPrefSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT / 10);
        textField.setOnKeyPressed(ke -> {
            if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
                itemList.getItems().add(0, textField.getText());
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });

        VBox box = new VBox(textField, itemList);
        box.setPrefSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        Scene scene = new Scene(box, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(new NativeKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
                boolean isAltPressed = (e.getModifiers() & NativeKeyEvent.ALT_MASK) != 0;
                boolean isShiftPressed = (e.getModifiers() & NativeKeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK) != 0;

                if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_V && isShiftPressed && isAltPressed) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        Point mouseLocation = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();

                        primaryStage.setX(mouseLocation.getX());
                        primaryStage.setY(mouseLocation.getY());
                        primaryStage.show();
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent nativeKeyEvent) {}
            @Override
            public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent nativeKeyEvent) {}
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: там вроде есть метод toFront()

Comment: тоже не помогает